# Bind a Swift or Objective-C library into my Xamarin.forms project

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, maui

I am attempting to bind a 3rd party iOS library into my Xamarin.forms application (ex:https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/guides/). I have successfully been able to do this with a Xamarin.iOS test project but not with a Xamarin.forms project.

Is there anyway I can do this with a Xamarin.forms project? Can this be done if I upgrade to .Net Maui?

Comment: you need to use DependencyService or a custom renderer to expose the iOS library to the Forms project

Comment: Your Xamarin Forms solution has a "YourApp.ios" project. Xamarin.iOS code goes there. Then do what Jason says.

Comment: Trust in the Jason, and all will be well.